# print all the employee name for a selected department id?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm using this code to save all the employee data when I selected a particular department (name) and use that department name (fetching their department id) and using that id to search all the employee data or all the employee data which is similar to that department id is saved into array and print that. But when i used that code, it prints employee id nil and print all the employee name(for all department id)

[image]

```
if let deptt = dictData["departments"] as? [Any] {

                print(deptt)

                for i in deptt as! [[String : Any]]
                {
                    let depttName = i["name"] as? String
                    let depttID = i["id"] as? String
                    //print(i["name"]!)

                    if depttName == selectedDeptt
                    {
                        let dd = depttID
                        print("dddd : \(dd)")

                        let emp = dictData["employees"] as? [Any]

                        for j in emp as! [[String : Any]]
                        {
                            let empID = j["department_id"] as? String
                            let empName = j["name"] as? String

                            print("Employee ID is : \(String(describing: empID))")

                            if depttID == empID
                            {
                                print("Employee ID is : \(String(describing: empID))")
                                print("Employee Names : \(String(describing: empName))")
                                arrEmp.append(empName!)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
print(arrEmp)
```

Comment: `let depttID = i["id"] as? String` Does it work? Is `i["id"]` really a `String` or a `Number`? Same for `j["department_id"]`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the table is already created. Its entity and attributes are

**Employee(name,id,salary,age,experience)**

```
select name from employee where id = 45;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, You are comparing department id with employee ID, Which will not match. You should fetch department ID for employee and then compare that ID with selected department ID.

Comment: I am comparing department id from the department key with the department id which is in the employee key.